# Many-to-many reference in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

We need to make many-to-many references in Drupal 7. We have Book content type and Author content type. Book contains field 'authors', so it may refer to multiple Authors. We use [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to bind entities.

How can we display Books bound with selected Author? How can we do that
- without adding a field 'books' to Author content type
- with Views module

If you know some good solutions of the 'many-to-many' problem in Drupal7, please write it. Any advice is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using views and use "authors" field as a contextual filter ?!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as a contextual filter, even without PHP validators